# Average Joe is busy

Tags: discussion

It seems that "Average Joe" is pretty power hungry.

[image]

I know that this isn't a question, but I just thought that this was funny, as it was 2 different people asking questions about (relatively) the same topic, and both used the hypothetical "Average Joe".

Comment: The first question inspired the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this can still be answered, there are several explanations:

- Joe plans to take over the world from his microstate
- Joe failed to take over the world and now he just has a microstate
- Joe thinks his microstate is the world
- Joe is hungry for power
- Joe has big plans for when he grows up

(Not a serious answer, just giving you something to answer on this question)